# Create plane with vertices at multiple objects' origins

Tags: modeling, vertices

I'm completely new to Blender, and I have been playing around in it to create some atomic-level models of crystal structures. I've been using the Atomic Blender add-on to create spheres for atoms and cylinders for bonds.

I would like to create polyhedra as well, so I'm trying to figure out how to add planes between atoms. **Is there a simple way to create planes with vertices located at the origins of the spheres?**

For reference, in the image below, I am trying to make a triangular plane between the selected spheres.

[image: Three atoms on a triangular face of a cuboctahedron are selected.]

Furthermore, if there's a way to add planes in a more automated manner, that would be great to know too.

Comment: You can duplicate a sphere, and in Edit mode select all and press M > Merge at Center in order to have one unique vertex, then join 3 vertices into one object (Ctrl J), in Edit mode select the 3 vertices and press F to Fill

Comment: You may want to look at this https://www.youtube.com/c/CGFigures/videos to get some ideas.

Comment: @RickT Thanks! I actually found their video on making crystal structures, which is what motivated me to pick up and play around with blender. They have a lot of videos, so it might take me a while to get through them all.

Comment: @moonboots Thank you! I find that this works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is no simple method to do this. you have to do it with your hands. join spheres (ctrl+j), select sphere (point the mouse on it and press L), then place cursor on the center of sphere (shift+s and drag mouse down), then add single vertex. repeat with another spheres, and then you can make plane with vertexes that you have created (select required vertexes and press f)

Comment: This worked pretty well, except I had issues trying to select the vertices in the center of the spheres without selecting vertices on the surface of the sphere. I combined this technique with moonboot's comment (above), where I merged at center for each sphere, then used the fill function. Thank you!